# issue with checkbox display on Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my model i have the following property.

```
public bool? ShowDocumentNumber { get; set; }
```

when i try to show it on the razor view

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model =>model.ShowDocumentNumber)
```

I get the following error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

when i try to cast it

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model =>bool.Parse(model.ShowDocumentNumber.ToString()))
```

i get the following error at run time.

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

How can i display the checkbox on the razor view?

Comment: Check box should have only two values true or false, checked or unchecked. It shouldn't be nullable

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first check if the nullable bool has a value

```
@if (Model.ShowDocumentNumber.HasValue)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ShowDocumentNumber.Value)
}
```